# How can I have my CMS upgrade itself?

Tags: php, codeigniter, content-management-system

I've built a CMS (using the Codeigniter PHP framework) that we use for all our clients. I'm constantly tweaking it, and it gets hard to keep track of which clients have which version. We really want everyone to always have the latest version.

I've written it in a way so that updates and upgrades generally only involve uploading the new version via FTP, and deleting the old one - I just don't touch the `/uploads` or `/themes` directories (everything specific to the site is either there or in the database). Everything is a module, and each module has it's own version number (as well as the core CMS), as well as an install and uninstall script for each version, but I have to manually FTP the files first, then run the module's install script from the control panel. I wrote and will continue to write everything personally, so I have complete control over the code.

What I'd like is to be able to upgrade the core CMS and individual modules from the control panel of the CMS itself. This is a "CMS for Dummies", so asking people to FTP or do anything remotely technical is out of the question. I'm envisioning something like a message popping up on login, or in the list of installed modules, like "New version available".

I'm confident that I can sort out most of the technical details once I get this going, but I'm not sure which direction to take. I can think of ways to attempt this with cURL (to authenticate and pull source files from somewhere on our server) and PHP's native filesystem functions like `unlink()`, `file_put_contents()`, etc. to preform the actual updates to files or stuff the "old" CMS in a backup directory and set up the new one, but even as I'm writing this post - it sounds like a recipe for disaster.

I don't use git/github or anything, but I have the feeling something like that could help? How should (or shouldn't) I approach this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Theres a bunch of ways to do this but the least complicated is just to have Git installedo n your client servers and set up a cron job that runs a git pull origin master every now and then. If your application uses Migrations it should be easy as hell to do.

You can do this as it sounds like you are in full control of your clients. For something like PyroCMS or PancakeApp that doesn't work because anyone can have it on any server and we have to be a little smarter. We just download a ZIP which contains all changed files and a list of deleted files, which means the file system is updated nicely.

We have a list of installations which we can ping with a HTTP request so the system knows to run the download, or the click can hit "Upgrade" when they log in.

Comment: Say for instance I want to make changes to the database, use a cron job for that as well? For instance, run a script or two from the **new** files once they have been updated/uploaded? I haven't used "Migrations" (assume it's a CI library I have not heard of), would that be a way to handle that situation?

Comment: ...and I was afraid that pulling a whole zip of the entire app would be too much, but I'd be happy to use that method if it will work. Grab the zip, delete/move the old app, extract? Simple as that? I was afraid it might kill the session or have other, more disastrous effects.

Comment: Replacing the whole application would be a damn nightmare and break a LOT of stuff... I said download a zip of changed file.s You'll want to write a bash script that is essentially diffing between tags in your local VCS and creating a list of changes. Look into Git, .diff, etc. You can't do advanced stuff without getting advanced. OR as I said, install git on your client servers and just run "git pull origin master" in cron. Migrations are a new CI library yes.

Comment: Yeah sorry I just misread. I figured replacing the whole thing would save the trouble of needing to know which version to update from (just update to the latest every time) but I guess that's just not reasonable, although I'm not exactly sure why it would "break a lot of stuff". I'm all for getting advanced, I just wasn't sure where to start and didn't want to get too advanced down the wrong path. Thanks for the advice, without using some sort of actual version control I can't see this being maintainable.

Comment: Be sure you're doing this over something like an ssh tunnel as well, or have some sort of code signing in place so you can verify the safety of the code you're updating to.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Git from your CMS: [Glip](https://github.com/patrikf/glip). The cron would be a url on your own system, without installing Git.

Comment: We're getting ready to actually go at this now, so I will take a look at this in detail shortly. In the meantime, have an upvote :) Thanks Alfonso

Comment: Wesley, @PhilSturgeon I hope you find it useful.

Answer (score 1):

@Obsidian Wouldn't a DNS poisoning attack also compromise most methods being mentioned in this thread?

Additionally SSH could be compromised by a man in the middle attack as well.

While total paranoia is a good thing when dealing with security, Wordpress being a GPL codebase would make it easy to detect an unauthorized code change in your code if such an attack did occur, so resolution would be easy.

SSH and Git does sound like a good solution, but what is the intended audience?

Comment: Code signing with having the public key of the distributor is virtually the only way to do it for mass-production.  Additionally, if an infected wordpress were released, it would require that the end-user system know what to expect of all the files, such as file checksums for everything updated.  Assuming wordpress' distribution method were compromised, it is safe to assume that those checksums would also be compromised and could be shipped to match the infected files.

Answer (score 0):

Have you taken a look at how WordPress does it?
That would seem to do what you want.
Check this page for a description of how it works.
http://tech.ipstenu.org/2011/how-the-wordpress-upgrade-works/

Comment: Don't recommend this, simply because WP blindly downloads an "update" if it "sees" it.  If someone manages to get a DNS poisoning attack against wordpress.org anytime soon (which is more common than most realize) and hijacks wordpress updating, it could cause a ton of systems to be infected.  Wordpress has, from what I recall, little to no measures in place to verify that it is a legitimate update and that it is safe to install (not surprising though, it IS wordpress after all - it isn't known for being a secure platform for a reason).

Comment: +1 Anyways, because this article gave me a lot of ideas. I didn't realize WP installed its own updates, or I would have taken a look at it sooner. I'm not too concerned (security wise) with third party code because I'll be in control of all the source files, and will have tested everything locally before making it available.

Comment: @WesleyMurch Look into what "man in the middle" attacks are. Doesn't matter if you have control of the source files; if you don't have control of the entire transmission route, you're vulnerable unless A) you encrypt with a strong algo B) you use code signing.  This is actually a giant opening with how Wordpress updates - all it takes, for them, would be a DNS poisoning attack and many times many installations could be infected/hijacked.

Comment: @Obsidian_: Thanks, we're looking into this right now and planning on using SSH with a git repo. Still learning the basics at the moment, please if you have something to share - add an answer!